# react native can't find package.json after workaround for load bundle 8081 failed

Tags: ios, json, react-native, localhost, runtime-error

Facing this error

*Failed to load bundle(http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:(Unable to resolve module (see pic below). Indeed, none of these files exist:*

[iOS Simulation Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mhjC0.png)

Other forums suggested workaround using

*rm ./node_modules/react-native/local-cli/core/**fixtures**/files/package.json*

Now I see the following error in terminal:

*No such file or directory*

How do I create this package.json? What is causing the localhost error and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same issue. The file you pointed to is probably this - 
`rm node_modules/react-native/local-cli/core/__fixtures__/files/package.json`

However, doing this didnt resolve my issue.